# Connect to MySQL in Docker container using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, ponyorm

I am using pony.orm to connect to mysqldb using a python code:

```
db.bind(provider='mysql', user=username, password=password, host='0.0.0.0', database=database)
```

And when I write the docker compose file:

```
  db:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
```

How can I pass the hostname to the python program by giving a value (in environment:) in the docker-compose.yml file ?

If I pass the value there can I access the value through os.environ['PARAM'] in the Python code?

Comment: is the python program running in docker-compose as well?

Comment: Same question as above. Is your Python program running in Docker? And is it in the same Docker network as your database container?

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes. I have created an image of the python program and added it to the docker compose file, so it is running as a different service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've named your service `db` in the `docker-compose.yaml`, you can use that as the `host`, provided you are on the same network:

```py
db.bind(provider='mysql', user=username, password=password, host='db', database=database)
```

To ensure you are on that network, in your `docker-compose.yaml`, at the bottom, you'll want:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: <your-network>
```

And you'll need to create that network before running `docker-compose up`

```sh
docker network create <your-network>
```

This avoids the need for an environment variable, as the container name will be added to the routing table of the network.

You don't *need* to define your own network, as `docker-compose` will handle that for you, but if you prefer to be a bit more explicit, it allows you the flexibility to do so. Normally, you would reserve this for multiple compose solutions that you wanted to join together on a single network, which is not the case here.

It's handled in `docker-compose` the same way you would do it in vanilla `docker`:

```sh
docker run -d -p 3308:3306 --network <your-network> --name db mariadb
docker run -it --network <your-network> ubuntu bash

# in the shell of the ubuntu container
apt-get update && apt-get install iputils-ping -y
ping -c 5 db

# here you will see the results of ping reaching container db
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4093ms
```

### Edit

As a note, per @DavidMaze's comment, the port you will be communicating with is 3306, since that's the port that the container is listening on, not 3308.

Comment: So, is the 'hostname' same with the service name?

Comment: Yes, I think you'll also want to specify the `port` when accessing `db` as well

Comment: So here in my case port should be 3308, please clarify?

Comment: Your port should be 3308, since that's the host port that it's mapped back to

Comment: Docker Compose will automatically create a network for you; you don’t need to do any of the manual `networks:` setup you describe.  You always need to use the port the server inside the container is listening on (for MySQL/MariaDB, 3306), not the external ports your `ports:` declarations (if any) map to.

Comment: @DavidMaze to your first point, usually when I'm using an externally defined network, `docker-compose` will complain saying that the network isn't defined yet, so that's from my experience. To your second point, it's been my understanding that the host port is exposed within the network, so that's the one you use. I'll do some debugging on my end, usually I don't change the `host:container` port mapping

Comment: @DavidMaze you're right, I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @DavidMaze Just re-read your comment, I addressed it incorrectly. Personally, I use my own networks, as it is a bit more explicit that way, you are right that docker-compose will allocate one for you

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi note, the port you will want is `3306`, *not* `3308`, my mistake

Comment: Ok. I later made both the ports to 3306.